# Error when attempting to enumerate an observable: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I am following the pattern found here (see hero.service.ts):
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Observable documentation found here:
https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/creating_and_subscribing_to_simple_observable_sequences.html

My code errors at the line shown below in ApplicationsIndex.ts.  The error message is "Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'".
My api server is being hit and returns data correctly.
When looking at the Typescript intellisense it appears this.Applications (and also "x" inside the subscribe() function)
is a collection object with find, forEach, etc methods.  It appears rxjs is loading correctly otherwise .map would not work.. What am I doing wrong?

sysemjs.config.json

```
var map = {
    'app': 'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular'
};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
};
```

main.ts

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
//...
```

ApplicationsIndex.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { PermissionsService} from '../services/permissionsService';
import { Application } from '../model/Application';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-applications-index',
    templateUrl: './app/permissions/applicationsIndex.html'
})
export class ApplicationsIndex implements OnInit
{
    public Title: string;
    public Applications: Application[];

    constructor(private permissionsService: PermissionsService)
    {
        this.Title = 'This is rolesIndex';
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.permissionsService.GetApplications().subscribe(x => {
            this.Applications = x;
            this.Applications.forEach((app, index) => { // ****** ERROR HERE  ******
                alert(app.Name);
            });
            alert('get apps done');
        });       
    }
}
```

PermissionsService.ts

```
GetApplications(): Observable<Application[]> {
    let url = this.serviceURL + 'Permissions/GetApplications';
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}


private extractData(res: Response) {
    if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
        throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
    }
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
}

private handleError(error: any) {
    let errorMsg = error.message || 'Server error';
    console.error(errorMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errorMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have perhaps a problem within your `extractData` method

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
  if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
    throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
  }
  let body = res.json();
  return body || []; // <-----------
}
```

If you receive directly an array in your response payload you don't need to use `body.data`. Otherwise your code seems correct.